# Very weird position "snapping" with simple box colliders?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, collider

Im not even sure what is happening here but I'm just trying to make objects fall normally onto the floor - they need gravity/be able to be pushed around, but just fall onto a static floor object.

I have a cube and my floor mesh. Floor mesh has this:

[image]

Cube has this:

[image]

Initially I'll have my cube just positioned right over the floor. Then I press play and pause, within one second it's 100 m away, spinning/falling. What could be happening here?

Comment: Can you please recheck the collider shapes. And also try changing the `Collision Detection` from `Discrete` to `Continuous` . And let's see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Could you add a "video" of what is happening (I can recommend [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) for that)? I don't really get how `within one second it's 100 m away, spinning/falling.` actually looks like

Answer (score 0):

You may face problems with small size colliders due to how the physics engine works. Increase size of colliders and see if it helps. If you really need colliders this small, try changing the `Default Contact Offset` in `Physics Manager`.